# How to join two CSV files in Powershell with SQL LIKE syntax

Tags: sql, powershell, join

I have two CSV files:

CSV_1:

```
Name,Age,
John,20
Amy,25
Joe,30
```

CSV_2:

```
Name,Address
JohnDoe,123 street
AmyDoe,456 street
JoeSmith,789 drive
```

Is there a way to join them together in Powershell using SQL LIKE syntax?

For example:

```
select *, csv2.address from csv1
left join csv2 on csv2.Name LIKE (csv1.Name + '%%')
```

I tried to use the JOIN-OBJECT module but it doesn't look like there is way to use this kind of filtering. Or maybe I cannot find an example to do it. It has to be done in Powershell due to some restrictions. Any help on this is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Name,Age,
John,20
Amy,25
Joe,30
'@

$b = ConvertFrom-Csv @'
Name,Address
JohnDoe,123 street
AmyDoe,456 street
JoeSmith,789 drive
'@
```

Using this [`Join-Object script`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join)/[`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)), you might do something like this:

```
$a |Join $b -Using { $Right.Name -Like "$($Left.Name)*" }

Name            Age Address
----            --- -------
{John, JohnDoe} 20  123 street
{Amy, AmyDoe}   25  456 street
{Joe, JoeSmith} 30  789 drive
```

To separate the names:

```
$a |Join $b -Using { $Right.Name -Like "$($Left.Name)*" } -Name A,B

AName BName    Age Address
----- -----    --- -------
John  JohnDoe  20  123 street
Amy   AmyDoe   25  456 street
Joe   JoeSmith 30  789 drive
```

Note that besides the fact that there is a risk that e.g. a `Jon` will be matched with a `JonathanDoe`, the `-Using` parameter is rather slow.
If the full names are actually in [`camelCase`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case) or `PascalCase`, it will be faster  to strip off the surname first (which might be done for both sides):

```
'JohnDoe' -CReplace '(?<=.+)[A-Z]+.*'
John
```

```
$a |Join $b -On { $_.Name -CReplace '(?<=.+)[A-Z]+.*' } -Name A,B

AName BName    Age Address
----- -----    --- -------
John  JohnDoe  20  123 street
Amy   AmyDoe   25  456 street
Joe   JoeSmith 30  789 drive
```